# Javascript code infinite loop

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I'm making a function, which takes an array of values and returns an array with only unique values. For example:

```
var strings = ["audi", "audi", "bmw", "bmw","bmw","bmw","audi","audi", "8-()"];
```

Result should be:

```
alert( unique(strings) ); // audi, bmw, 8-()
```

I don't understand why my function goes into infinite loop, could anyone help please?
Here is the function:

```
function unique(arr) {
   var result = [];
   result.push(arr[0]);

   for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
           if  (result[j] != arr[i]) {
              result.push(arr[i]); 
           }
       }
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: `result.push(arr[i])` makes `result.length` increase by 1.

Comment: your `result` array will never stop to grow

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger, or adding some `console.log()` statements in the loop(s)?

Comment: @Pointy doesn't push() automaticly update arrays length that it pushes to?

Comment: @qazerty23 exactly this is the problem it gets bigger and bigger

Comment: Your condition is `i < arr.length`, and you're making `arr.length` grow continuously.

Comment: Ok, I got it! How should I fix this to work properly?

Comment: I don't get an infinite loop when I run the above code, but the logic is faulty. If the current `arr[i]` item is not equal to the first value in `result` then you add it to `result` even though it may be equal to one of the later values in `result`. And if it's not equal to any of the existing `result` values you'll add it multiple times...

Comment: @qazerty23: Just think through exactly what is happening in each step to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, in spite of all the answers that pretty much just show code, be sure to analyse what you were doing so you can understand what was wrong and how it would be fixed given your original approach. Understanding these sorts of problems is very important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for nested loop. you can check the result for available values with `Array.prototype.indexOf` or `Array.prototype.includes` methods.

```js
var strings = ["audi", "audi", "bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "audi", "audi", "8-()"];

function unique(arr) {
  var result = [];
  result.push(arr[0]);

  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (result.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1)
      result.push(arr[i]);


  }
  return result;
}
console.log(unique(strings))
```

#### BTW chef suggest is:

```js
var strings = ["audi", "audi", "bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "audi", "audi", "8-()"];
console.clear();

var result = strings.filter(function(s){ return this[s] ? false : (this[s] = true); }, Object.create(null))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: there is no `this` in arrow functions.

Comment: This still looks like a nested loop, assuming that indexOf() is built using a loop inside, meaning the speed is O(N)^2 (the for loop times the indexOf loop)

Comment: @specimen You're right about first one which where used to increase performance of OP's implementation.

Answer (score 7):

You can make it very simpler with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`spread operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) belongs to ES6,

```
var unique = src => [...new Set(src)]
```

By the way your logic is wrong. It will not run into an infinite loop. But it will give you an undesirable result.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it simpler: using Array.reduce

```js
var values = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,62,2,2]

function getUniq(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(u, value) {
    if (u.indexOf(value) < 0) u.push(value)
    return u;
  }, [])
}

console.log(getUniq(values))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce the time complexity of this

```
var strings = ["audi", "audi", "bmw", "bmw","bmw","bmw","audi","audi", "8-()"];

var unique = [];

strings.forEach(function(str){
  if (unique.indexOf(str) < 0) {
     unique.push(str)
  }
});

return unique;
```

Comment: The `.indexOf()` operation is still a linear (*O(n)*) operation.

Comment: We can use Object over here

Comment: Right, an Object or (with ES2015) a Set instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) also

```
var strings = ["audi", "audi", "bmw", "bmw","bmw","bmw","audi","audi", "8-()"];
var uniq = new Set(strings);

// if you need in array 
uniq = Array.from(uniq);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a dictionary/hashtable for this. Then the total runtime should be O(N) for looping through `arr` once:

```
function unique(arr) {
    unique = {}
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        unique[arr[i]]=true
    }
    return Object.keys(unique)
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49srtxpp/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You could change the inner loop a bit and use a variable `found` for checking if the value is in the result array.

This variable is also needed to check if the value is to push to the result set.

Additionally you could use a `break` to exit the inner loop if a duplicate value is found.

```js
function unique(arr) {
    var result = [],
        found;

    result.push(arr[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        found = false;                            // initial set to false
        for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            if (result[j] === arr[i]) {
                found = true;                     // set to true to skip push
                break;                            // exit loop
            }
        }
        found || result.push(arr[i]);             // push only, if not found
    }
    return result;
}

var strings = ["audi", "audi", "bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "audi", "audi", "8-()"];

console.log(unique(strings)); // audi, bmw, 8-()
```

A shorter ES6 proposal with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and a hash table as closure.

```js
function unique(arr) {
    return arr.filter((temp => a => !temp[a] && (temp[a] = true))(Object.create(null)));
}

var strings = ["audi", "audi", "bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "audi", "audi", "8-()"];

console.log(unique(strings)); // audi, bmw, 8-()
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer. Sometimes it's good to check back my own answers.

Comment: Which one is better? break the loop or add found to the loop second statement? or for simplicity `for( var j = 0; j < result.length && ( found = result[j] === arr[i] ) ; j++);`

Comment: @mortezaT, it depends, but it's not wrong to use `break`. i think it is good to use all language features, where it makes sense.

Comment: That's OK and there is no issue about this doesn't work. Every where I see they say better not to use `jump` or `break` because of better readability.

Answer (score 0):

another fastest way, it is taking 2 milli seconds [check the performance](https://jsfiddle.net/r23k0b70/)

```
var dupEleArr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 20, 3, 3, 3, 32, 324, 5, 52];
var uniqueArr = dupEleArr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a-b;
}).filter(function(ele,i,arr){
   return arr.length > 3 ? arr[i] != arr[i+1] : (arr.length == 2) ? (arr[i] != arr[i+1]) : true;
});
```

[check jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqct92h3/)

Comment: Using dictionary is at least 10x faster. I tried your jsfiddle with a bigger dataset: https://jsfiddle.net/49srtxpp/1/ Your solution took 30 ms, with dict it took 3ms. See my answer. BTW: Only commented on this since you presented it as _the fastest way_.

Comment: hey thank you @specimen , because of you, i learn the fastest technique... see here https://jsfiddle.net/2en1aejr/ i did in 3 ways but thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

push() Pushes a new object to the beginning of an array and pushes everything back!

Let's view the state of your arrays in the program:

```
arr = [A,B]    result = [A]    i = 1

j = 0 -> arr[i] = B and result[j] = A    
so we use push: result = [B,A] and j++

j = 1 -> arr[i] = B and result[j] = A
so we use push: result = [B,B,A] and j++

j = 2 -> arr[i] = B and result[j] = A
so we use push: result = [B,B,B,A] and j++
```

Your array keeps increasing and the check will never fail, since you append to the beginning of your array and not the end.

But even if you appended your new Item to the end, you would not get unique results, since you have to check **every** element in result and only if not any of the results is the same you should add your new element to the result array.

For better solutions see the other answers -> Use a **Set** with `contains()`